# How to diagnose “Invalid block type ” error?

Tags: php, blocks, error

How to diagnose “Invalid block type ”

Not sure how to figure out this **error**, I've been googling for a week and I can't 
seem to find a solution. Any ideas?

```
    exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'סוג בלוק מידע לא תקני: Mage_Page_Block_Html_CookieNotice' in /var/www/magento/app/Mage.php:594
        Stack trace:
        #0 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('?????? ????????...')
        #1 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('page/html_cooki...', Array)
        #2 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('page/html_cooki...', 'global_cookie_n...')
        #3 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('page/html_cooki...', 'global_cookie_n...')
        #4 /var/www/magento/app/code/local/Smartwave/All/Model/Core/Layout.php(40): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
        #5 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
        #6 /var/www/magento/app/code/local/Smartwave/All/Model/Core/Layout.php(31): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
        #7 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(206): Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
        #8 /var/www/magento/app/code/local/Smartwave/All/Model/Core/Layout.php(31): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
        #9 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(206): Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
        #10 /var/www/magento/app/code/local/Smartwave/All/Model/Core/Layout.php(31): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
        #11 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout->generateBlocks()
        #12 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
        #13 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(90): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout()
        #14 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Cms_IndexController->defaultNoRouteAction()
        #15 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('defaultNoRoute')
        #16 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(201): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
        #17 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
        #18 /var/www/magento/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
        #19 /var/www/magento/index.php(89): Mage::run('', 'store')
        #20 {main}`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

this block is defined in the layout `page.xml`

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="before_body_end" as="before_body_end" translate="label">
    <label>Page Bottom</label>
    <block type="page/html_cookieNotice" name="global_cookie_notice" as ="global_cookie_notice" template="page/html/cookienotice.phtml" before="-" />
</block>
```

And class itself is `Mage_Page_Block_Html_CookieNotice` (`app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/CookieNotice.php`). Check if this class exists in your installation and file is readable.

What version of Magento are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.
version 1.7 , and this file is missing , i dont have it

Comment: this class was added later. And looks like your theme is based on the layout for 1.9 version. You can remove block `global_cookie_notice` from  the theme layout, or upgrade magento, or try to add class and configuration options for it manually